# ChartJS linechart edit yAxis labels

Tags: chart.js, linechart

Trying to get a linechart in ChartJS working according to the wishes of our clients, but I've run into an issue: When an entire week of data (we do sales) is 0, the labels plotted on the yAxis go below 0 -which is something our clients don't want. I've looked at **scaleoverride**, **suggestedMin**, and **beginAtZero** but none worked.

How can I change the labels so it will always have 0 as a minimum?

Complimentary image below, to visualise the issue:

[image]

The code (with one of the not-working methods I've tried):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('salesChart').getContext('2d');
salesChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 10,
    scaleStepWidth: 20,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    data: {
        labels: chartLabels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sales',
            data: chartData,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(37,185,153,0.7)"
        }],
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
     scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Note: I left the rest of the chart config as is. You did not explicitly supply the chartLabels and chartData variables, so I used:

```
var chartLabels = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var chartData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3c4yq5oq/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried what you said, but it's still not working. I also tried to copy+pasted the entire **options** block from your post. 
Apologies about the labels; they're dynamically made.

Do you maybe have a *fiddle* that works?

Comment: @Zubaja I've just added it to the end of the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. No idea what happened, but at some point (between my previous reply and this one), your solution worked.